# Why does Eclipse not show import suggestions for packages in System Libraries like com.sun.net.httpserver?

Tags: java, eclipse, http

I've been trying to learn networking/server development on Java without the use of any frameworks. The first option that came to me was the HttpServer class which is defaulted in System Libraies under the com.sun.net.httpserver package. I noticed however, that I have to manually import this package every time, Eclipse isn't showing the import suggestions like it does normal system library packages. After testing around I noticed it's doing this for a lot of the system library packages, mostly ones starting with jdk (jdk.httpserver for example which is where the com.sun.net.httpserver package is).

I've tried manually adding the package to the build path, I uninstalled and reinstalled eclipse, I've tried a different JRE's and nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Look at "Java > Appearance > Type Filters" in the Preferences. They are probably filterered out there.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, unless you are using an old version of Java, anything outside `java` and `javax` packages aren't directly accessible to developers. What Java version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in [Oracle's Java FAQ page](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html). The reason is that packages under sun.* and any other packages that come with the Java/JDK distribution are not part of the Java standard. They are implementation classes that come with no guarantee of compatibility or stability. Developers are advised against using them to prevent breaking their applications when new versions of Java are released. This has caused problems in the past. It should not be used in production applications.

Also note that the class that you are trying to use is extremely limited in functionality and doesn't resemble real HTTP application development.